# To put my folder(or the alias of it) into the root directory, how to do with the asl.conf file?

Tags: folders, root, configuration-profiles

I have a requirement to put files in the root directory. I learned from [this website](https://sw0zwl.medium.com/how-to-create-a-directory-in-root-on-catalina-or-big-sur-e58e459461a) that I can modify /etc/syslog.conf to achieve this goal, but when I open it, I am prompted that the relevant configuration has been transferred to /etc/asl.conf, so I open asl.conf, but I don't know the syntax inside. How should I modify it?

Comment: The website you link to talks about modifying /etc/synthetic.conf, and also explains the syntax. Not sure why you want to modify syslog.conf instead (which is about logging).

Comment: Also, there are several questions conceringn synthetic.conf already on the site, maybe you can have a look at them to see whether the information there is enough to help you.

Comment: Oh, I missed syslog.conf to synthetic.conf, sorry for that. I've tried making synthetic.conf and it works. Thank you!